# How do I return Collision target from the particle trigger module?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development, particle-system

I'm a new in Unity.

I wanted to make a game has some features in the particle system interact with the game environment.
So I was using a Collision module or trigger module to the particles directly affect the game environment.

I was going to verify it first to using collision Mudule. bcuz it takes a long time to make the particle's function into a bullet system from the start.

[image]

The first problem is that every time I use CollisionModule, the Particle Collide and flies away without RigidBody.

[image]

The second problem was the trigger module does not return the collision target.

If I simply tried to make the projectile disappear after an attack, I could use the collision module,
but I wish my projectile could penetrate the enemy.

[image]

This is the result I made with only trigger modules and sub-emmiters, and it's what I wanted look like.

I hope monster get actual damage to the bullet collided
and get information about the victim from a script from the particle or attacker or victim, but I can't find a way.

[image]

I hope the script can detect the Collision event with the collider or victim gameObject

In the past, posted on StackOverflow and Unityy manuals have only been said to have no relevant information or functionality yet.

I don't want to use raycast because it can't sync with the speed of the particle,

A bullet system that creates moving independent objects and summons moving particles as children is still not fit for purpose.

What I do now is spawn a boxCollider with the "isTrigger" check on the victin's position for 0.1 seconds to identify the hit, but I'm not sure if it will work.

I hope it can solved. Thank you!!!

Comment: Please dont put links to pictures of code - put the code in your question

Comment: Almost everything is done with editor functions (animated events, root motion, particle trigger modules...) instead of code.
Threr is no code to show except for the basic movement of the character and the launch method with a single line of "particle.Play" triggered by an animated event.

The "OnParticleTrigger" code is empty, as shown above.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me, but could you not just add a rigidbody and collider to the bullet, and then listen for collisions in either OnTriggerEnter or OnCollisionEnter? There'd be no need to 'spawn a boxcollider for 0.1 second'

Comment: In that case, all launch and movement types provided by the particle system, such as acceleration, deceleration, collision trigger, deadTrigger, orbit, SizeOverLifeTime, Noise, burst, RateOverTime, Duration, arc, randomSpread, burstSpread etc., must be newly code.
Particle systems basically offer various types of movement, collision, and trigger, I just wanted to see if the system works, using particles and collision module, before I make them all new myself.